# Cucumber6 witn Java11 Datatable transformation into List of Enums

Tags: cucumber, testng, java-11, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I updated project from Cucumber4 > Cucumber6 and from JDK8 > JDK11. Problem is with a couple of tests that I have. I have scenario:

```
    Then Relevant link on Checkout page is valid
    # LinkType enum
    | LOGO | LOGIN | TERMS | PRIVACY_POLICY | CONTACT | FAQ |
```

Code implementation is:

```
    @Then("^Relevant link on Checkout page is valid$")
    public void relevantLinkOnCheckoutPageIsValid(DataTable dataTable) {
    List<LinkType> links = dataTable.asList(LinkType.class);
```

And this was working until update. Problem is that old transformation is not working anymore and I didn't found how to add new transformer so I can transform dataTable to list of enums that I have.

Can someone suggest something or maybe link for some documentation where I can check what to implement?

Comment: Did you define a datatable type for the enum? https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#data-table-type

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Hi @M.P.Korstanje, error that I'm getting is 

`Step failed
io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException: Can't convert DataTable to List<ch.tamedia.model.constants.LinkType>.
Please review these problems:

 - There was no table entry or table row transformer registered for ch.tamedia.model.constants.LinkType.
   Please consider registering a table entry or row transformer.`

Problem is that I don't have datatable type for this enum. It is not clear to me what and how to return values from that method? Should I just rerutn enum value from provided string?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#data-table-type

Something like this should do the trick:

```java
@DataTableType
public LinkType linkType(String cell) {
    return LinkType.valueOf(cell);
}

@Then("^Relevant link on Checkout page is valid$")
public void relevantLinkOnCheckoutPageIsValid(@Transpose List<LinkType> links) {

}
```

The data table type will transform each table cell into a instance of a `LinkType` enum. Then in the step definition the `@Transpose` annotation will transpose the table so that it is now a vertical list rather then a horizontal one. Then Cucumber will use the data table type to transform the individual cells into a `List<LinkType>`.

You can also use:

```
List<LinkType> links = dataTable.transpose().asList(LinkType.class);
```

Comment: This one is problem solver. Just to mark that annotation is @Transpose, but it is trivial change. Thanks a lot for helping :beer: